# How to fix locale issue in Red Hat distro?

Tags: python, locale, rhel

I'm having a strange problem today in my RHEL system. My python script is returning:

```
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/locale.py", line 513, in setlocale
    return _setlocale(category, locale)
locale.Error: unsupported locale setting
```

WHen I run...

```
$ locale
```

The ouput is...

```
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
...
```

I have been trying many suggestions but none of them solved my issue yet.

For example:

- Reinstall glibc-common.
- Export LC_ALL as environment variable into ~/.bashrc.
- Change the file /etc/sysconfig/i18n'.
- locale-gen does not exists in RHEL.

Does anyone has a good suggestion to solve my issue. Remembering that I'm using RHEL and not Ubuntu (there are many tutorials about locale issues and Ubuntu).

Comment: [moved from old not-an-answer] Does [Fixing locale and setlocale LC issues in CentOS and RHEL](http://blog.earth-works.com/2014/02/10/fixing-lc-locale-issues-in-centos-and-rhel/) help? What do you get from these shell commands: `locale -a`, `locale -k LC_IDENTIFICATION`, `LANG='en_US.utf8' python -c "import locale;print locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')"`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add this to your `/etc/environment`:

```
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
```

Then logout and login to shell again and try executing your commands.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was iTerm setting the locale variables automatically. I fixed it by going to the iTerm menu and then

```
Preferences ... > Profiles > "select your profile" > Terminal > uncheck "Set locale variables automatically"
```

Answer (score -3):

The addition to /etc/environment of following variables fixed my issue:

LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8

Good answer above.